# Apple submission failing with missing icons using Xcode5 and Images.xcassets using wildcarded distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am doing contract work for another company and they finally submitted the build to Apple. I am using a wildcarded distribution profile for TestFlight builds and they re-sign it before submitting to Apple.

I've recently switched to using the Images.xcassets for the AppIcon and everything looked good from Xcode. No warnings about app icons or archiving errors, however, when they submit to Apple it doesn't get past the Meta-data review because of missing app icons. Specifically, the following:

- Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
  wrapper:AppIcon40x40
- Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
  wrapper:AppIcon60x60
- Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
  wrapper:AppIcon50x50
- Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
  wrapper:AppIcon72x72
- Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
  wrapper:AppIcon76x76
- iPad:AppIcon57x57.png: icon dimensions (57x57) don't meet the size
  requirements. The icon file must be 72x72, in .png format

All the other icons (building for iOS 6/7 universal app) appear to be fine. I made sure the .xcassets was part of my target and all the other various suggestions here.

So I opened up the .ipa and Payload to check out what Xcode had done. With the exception of AppIcon60x60, it changed the names of my files to AppIcon40x40~iPad and simliar for the rest of them. AppIcon60x60 was actually called AppIcon60x60@2x (which makes sense because it is 120x20 px). The file names in the Info.plist did not contain the ~iPad suffix for the iPad icons, which I feel lead the the issue of rejection.

I was under the impression when you use the Images.xcassets that Xcode would automatically name the icons and fill out the Info.plist appropriately. I am left wondering if it is a problem with archiving the app with a wildcarded distribution profile.

I eventually got the submission to be a success by removing the Images.xcassets and manually assigning the icons and then going into the Info.plist and deleting a few extra entries that were lying around. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/TransitionGuide.pdf):

> Note:
>   An asset catalog contains resources that are displayed within a napp; an asset catalog doesn’t
>   hold the app icon, launch image, or any other image that an outside
>   process needs to access.

I moved these files out of the xcassets, restored the .plist Icon Files, and worked.

Comment: Right, that is how I got mine to work as well. But why does Apple include a 'Use Asset Catalog' option in the Project settings if it doesn't work?